# inserting a post from an extern php file but post content doesn't show on wp site

Tags: php, wp-query, database, wp-admin, mysql

I'm doing a php file that insert post's on my wordpress site. I'm filling  all the fields in wp_posts, but the content doesn't shows on my wordpress site. I wonder if it's because the categories are empty, and googling I've found that categories are beeing stored in wp_term_taxonomy. But looking at that table, I don't even understand how or were to add a category. So If anyone could throw me some light on this, I'll appreciate.

This is my php code to insert on database:

```
//Mysqli Connection
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass.", "dbname");
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error de Conexión (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }   

//securize strings 
    $softonicDescription[$key2] = $mysqli->real_escape_string($softonicDescription[$key2]);
    $title[$key2] = $mysqli->real_escape_string($title[$key2]);

    //insert data in mysql database
    $select = "INSERT INTO  `dbname`.`wp_posts` (
`ID` ,
`post_author` ,
`post_date` ,
`post_date_gmt` ,
`post_content` ,
`post_title` ,
`post_excerpt` ,
`post_status` ,
`comment_status` ,
`ping_status` ,
`post_password` ,
`post_name` ,
`to_ping` ,
`pinged` ,
`post_modified` ,
`post_modified_gmt` ,
`post_content_filtered` ,
`post_parent` ,
`guid` ,
`menu_order` ,
`post_type` ,
`post_mime_type` ,
`comment_count`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,
  '1',
   DATE(NOW()) ,
    DATE(NOW()) ,
      '$softonicDescription[$key2]',
        '$title[$key2]',
          '',
            'publish',
              'open',
                'open',
                  '',
                    '$title[$key2]',
                      '',
                        '',
                         DATE(NOW()) ,
                          DATE(NOW()) ,
                            '',
                              '0',
                                '',
                                  '0',
                                    'post',
                                      '',
                                        '0'
);
";

        if ($mysqli->query($select)) {
            echo ("query ok!<br><br>");
        }
```

Comment: Obviously because I'm doing this from an external file. It is a file that take content from outside with curl connections and once it has the data it insert it in my wordpress site. I could store this php file in the same server and do that the way you say but I'll need to import some php files, do you know which ones ?

Comment: You should probably use [Wordpress REST API](http://wp-api.org/guides/getting-started.html), it would prevent including multiple wp core file and would be more maintainable

Comment: I haven't seen any clear example on how to insert posts on a word press site from word press rest api, so I think it would be better idea to import some core php word press files and use the word press insert post methods instead

Comment: @user3033437 Ummm, there is a clear example in the lin that Antoine has send. Although that is for version 1. http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/ - Here is the manual for version 2 which is up to date.